# solving order of time in data structures

Tags: data-structures

I want the order time(theta) for these algorithms. Can you help me please?

1)

```
    For ( i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++ )
    {
        For( j=1 ; j<=n ; j++ )
            X++;
        n--;
     }
```

2)

```
For ( i = 1 ; i<=n ; i = i*2)
    For( j= 1 ; j <=n ; j = j*2 )
        For(k=1 ; k<=j ; K++)
            X++;
```

3)

```
For ( i=5 ; i<n-10 ; i++ )
    For ( j=i ; j>1 ; j-- )
        For ( k=1 ; k<j ; k++ )
        {
            S=S+k+j;
            S=S*2;
        }
```

Comment: How far did you get with this before posting it here ? People will be happy to help if you can show that you have made an effort on your own first.

Comment: It doesn't let me send photos Paul R. but I could only do some of the first question's solving.

Comment: So what answer did you get for the first question ?

Comment: I have got theta(n^2) for the first one.

Comment: Did you notice the `n--` in the inner loop ?

Comment: I edited it. It was a mistake.the n-- is in the first loop.

Comment: OK - so (1) is now O(n^2) then, as you say.

Comment: Can you help me with the second and the third one? I don't know how to solve them.

Comment: For the second one you have three loops - think about how many times each loop will execute.

Comment: I think the first and the second loop iterate for lg(n) times,and the third one n times.

Comment: Yes, log(n) for each of the two outer loops - the inner loop is tricky though...

Comment: Is the answer for the second one theta(nlg(n))?

Comment: Is it log(n) or lg(n)?(lg(n) means it is in the base of 2 instead of 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They answer for the above question is:
1) theta(n^2)
2)theta(nlgn)
3)theta(n^3)